# JQuery onclick attribute undefined in each() loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please forgive my awful coding style. I am learning to write a Chrome extension and can't figure out some JQuery stuff. I am trying to parse a document with some rows, each containing a (dynamically generated?) link, the HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="row" id="rand">
<div class="display">
    <div class="link">
        <a name="actionLink" href="#" alt="action" onclick="listener.postAction('form', 'http://***/')" class="alink"><span>Confirm</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am grabbing the info the following way:

```
$(".row").each(function(index)
{
  var $itemArea = $(this).find(".display");
  var id        = $(this).attr("id"); 
  var alink     = $(this).find(".link").find("a");
  var onclick   = alink.attr("onclick");

  console.log("id=" + id);
  console.log("alink=" + alink);
  console.log("onclick=" + onclick);
});
```

Here's the output from JSBin:

```
"id=rand"
"alink=[object Object]"
"onclick=listener.postAction('form', 'http://***/')"
```

However, when I debug this in Chrome, the value of "onclick" returned by my code is undefined. To make things more confusing, when I inspect the `onclick` attribute of `alink`, it shows the correct value? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what order is this code in?  Are you calling the javascript in the `<head>` or at the end of the `<body>` or somewhere else?

Comment: This code is run in `content_script.js` from the Chrome extension. The content script receives a message, then calls a function that parses the document.

Comment: If they are dynamically generated, try using `$(document).find('.row').each()` and see if it helps

Comment: I don't know much about extension writing, but maybe it's still possible that it runs before the DOM is loaded. Put your code inside `(document).ready()`.

Comment: @Deryck There's no different between those two things.

Comment: yeah I was kinda grasping I just didn't want to go the `$(document).ready()` route if it wasn't necessary.  I'm not sure what his extension is actually for

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to get your var instead

```
var onclick   = $('.link a:first',this).attr('onclick');
```